# Why is Goku not using instant transmission?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In the recent episode of DBS we see that Goku is seen flying to Krillin and Dendy - why he is not using instant transmission? If he used it, he could save some time and train for the tournament of power. Why is he not doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Goku is not about optimization or not concerned regarding the tournament. He is only looking forward to meet people with great power and test his limits against them.

Plus, many times it was shown many times (*I know I'll get roasted for this*) that Goku has become **over confident of his power** and even becoming vulnerable to attack during battles.  Also, its fun to fly around at high speeds.

So, he doesn't use instant transmission until its absolutely necessary and doesn't think he needs to train in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Goku is not an engineer, he does not aim to optimize his lifestyle nor does he plan  that far ahead.

If he started doing that he wouldn't be the Goku we know of he simply wouldn't be the character we know and love.

There are lots of things he could have done that would have been smart in Dragon Ball, Dragon Ball Z, GT and now super but he is who he is because he doesn't do those things.